# 404 not found. Using postman for stripe integration in android studio

Tags: android-studio, postman, stripe-payments, stripe-payment-intent

I added the url for customers, emphemeral keys and payment_intent in the postman, and then i added authorization, body and sent the url request. Customers is working but for emphemeral key and payment_intent, i get the 404 error even though I used all details from stripe documentation

{
"error": {
"message": "Unrecognized request URL (GET: /v1/ephemeral_keys). Please see https://stripe.com/docs or we can help at [https://support.stripe.com/."](https://support.stripe.com/.%22),
"type": "invalid_request_error"
}
}

Answer (score 1):

The `/v1/ephemeral_keys` only accepts the `POST` verb.